# how to use setter getter in java android?

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

i try to use encapsulation (setter getter) in my file java in my project android. but it not work, i don't know why. can you help me? i'll give my code

it's my setter and getter in Tahsin1_Jurus6.java

```
public class Tahsin1_Jurus6 extends Activity {

String judul;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tahsin1_jurus6);
}

public String getJudul() {
    return judul;
}

public void setJudul(String judul) {
    this.judul = judul;
}

public void contoh_ba(View view) {
    setJudul("Contoh huruf Ba");
    Intent tah1_jurus6_contoh = new Intent(Tahsin1_Jurus6.this,
            Tahsin1_Jurus6_Contoh.class);
    startActivity(tah1_jurus6_contoh);
    this.finish();
}
```

and in this class, i try to call value of "judul", and i want set my "textView1" with value of "judul"

```
public class Tahsin1_Jurus6_Contoh extends Activity {

TextView judul;
ImageView contoh;
String nama_judul = "dudud", nama_gambar = "";
Tahsin1_Jurus6 t1j6 = new Tahsin1_Jurus6();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tahsin1_jurus6_contoh);

    judul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    contoh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    nama();
    setNama_judul();
}

public void nama() {
    nama_judul = t1j6.getJudul();
    judul.setText(nama_judul);
    judul.setTextSize(20);
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how it doesn't work? Are you getting a compilation error? An exception? The wrong data?

Comment: that is not how you send information to an activity, please look at how to use intents correctly

Comment: @Mureinik after i export to apk, i try to install that to my device. when i access that activity, the layout was blank, none a word. there should a text  reads "Contoh Huruf Ba", but there is nothing a text.

Comment: @tyczj oke i'll try that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you need to create New Class for getters/setters

```
  public class JudulData
  {
    string judul;
    public String getJudul() {
        return judul;
    }

    public void setJudul(String judul) {
        this.judul = judul;
    }

  }
```

Use it by creating instance of class

```
JudulData jd=new JudulData();
//getting
jd.getJudul();
//setting
jg.setJudul("stringvalue");
```

Comment: for the instance, where i must write instance ? in method "onCreate" ??

Comment: yep,it should be like global in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse data beetween 2 activity in Android, you need to use Intent.
In your code just modify the Intent in *Tahsin1_Jurus6*  like this

```
Intent tah1_jurus6_contoh = new Intent(Tahsin1_Jurus6.this,
            Tahsin1_Jurus6_Contoh.class);
 tah1_jurus6_contoh.putExtra("name", ""+getJudul()); //the keyword is name
 startActivity(tah1_jurus6_contoh);
```

And in the *Tahsin1_Jurus6_Contoh* you should get the value like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...     
    String judul = getIntent().getStringExtra("name"); //get value by keyword
    ...
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: i already try this, but why when i click the button, it's appear "Unfortunately, ...."

Comment: I have modify my code again, please check it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate class as rajan ks wrote. Your above code is written in an android **activity**. Create a new java **class** file (this does not come with an XML layout file) and do the above.